# Overriding methods with stricter signature

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I'm programming in Java and have the following problem:

I would like to do collision detection. For that, I need different types of `BoundingBox`es. For the sake of example, let's say that I have entities that have a circular collision box and entities that have a rectangular bounding box. So I need two classes, `BoundingBoxCircle` and `BoundingBoxRectangle` to implement collision detection. Also, I would like to have an abstract class `BoundingBox` that has the abstract method `collidesWith(...)`, which takes as an argument some kind of `BoundingBox` and returns whether it is currently colliding with some other `BoundingBox`.

Now for the issue: I can't find a nice way to structure this programmatically. Essentially, I need to implement different collision detections between rectangles and circles (and potentially other shapes). I would also like to be able to call these methods "nicely". When I have a particular bounding box, say `BoundingBoxCircle`, I would like to be able to call `boundingBoxCircle.collidesWith(rectangle)` and have it dynamically dispatched to the method that handles circle-rectangle collision detection. However, this does not work:

```
public abstract class BoundingBox {
    public abstract boolean collidesWith(BoundingBox b);
}

public class BoundingBoxCircle {
    @Override
    public boolean collidesWith(BoundingBoxRectangle b) {
         ...
    }
}
```

Because the signature of the overriden method is not the same.

So I can think of two options:

- Provide all method signatures in the superclass
- Override `collidesWith` in all subclasses

The first one has the problem that I would have to provide the`circleCollidesWithRectangle`, `rectangleCollidesWithCircle` (etc.) signatures in the `BoundingBox` class, which is quite ugly, because I essentially have "information" in `BoundingBox` which should really be part of its subclasses.

The second one has the problem that I would need to override the `collidesWith(BoundingBox b)` method in each subclass, which means that I do not know which type `b` is of - so I would have to check for all cases in every subclass; essentially:

```
class BoundingBoxRectangle extends BoundingBox {
    @Override
    public boolean collidesWith(BoundingBox b) {
         if (b typeof BoundingBoxRectangle) {
             ...
         } else if (b typeof BoundingBoxCirce) {
             ...
         } else {
              throw new IllegalStateException("unexpected type");
         }
    }
}
```

...which could lead to an insane amount of if-statements if I start programming more subclasses for `BoundingBox`. It also has the disadvantage that I might forget to add an if-statement in the future, which are potentially hard to find, because I only throw an exception if the collision is checked for two specific entities.

I would really like to implement this in a way that let's me see missing methods at compile-time and does not require code repetition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can munge double dispatch into a single dispatch language with the [visitor pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor).  This is basically having an interface like:

```
bool collidesWith(BoundingBox visitor) {
    return visitor.collidesWithVisit(this);
}

bool collidesWithVisit(BoundingBoxRectangle other) {
    return false;
}

bool collidesWithVisit(BoundingBoxCircle other) {
    return false;
}
```

The main interface is through the first function, then it will call through to the appropriate implementation below.

Answer (score 2):

The usual advice, if you want to model this functionality in Java, is to transform your model until it can be implemented with single dispatch. For instance, you could have a shape-specific `Extent` property or method that doesn't compute collisions, but only where exactly a shape reaches, and then a shape-agnostic `CollisionManager` that actually checks for collisions, based on information that it gets from dynamically dispatched `getExtent()` calls on both objects.

This can mean that you have to change your model quite a bit, but the alternative would be to switch to a language that allows multple dispatch natively - and most people aren't prepared to start using Common Lisp just for that.

Comment: +1 for mentioning my pre-Java favorite language, being Common Lisp (in some aspects like multi-dispatch, still unsurpassed).

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, it would be incorrect to have a `collidesWith` abstract method in BoundingBox since even if you know how *your* implementation works, it isn't enough information to be able to determine if there is a collision.

You should create a `CollisionManager` containing a list of `CollisionHandler` classes like so:

```
public interface CollisionHandler {
    public boolean canHandle(Class<? extends BoundingBox> class1, Class<? extends BoundingBox> class2);
    public boolean collidesWith(BoundingBox instance1, BoundingBox instance2);
}

public class CollisionManager {
    List<CollisionHandler> handlers= new ArrayList<CollisionHandler>();

    public void add(CollisionHandler handler) {
        handlers.add(handler);
    }

    public boolean collidesWith(BoundingBox instance1, BoundingBox instance2) {
        for(CollisionHandler handler : handlers) {
            if(handler.canHandle(instance1.getClass(), instance2.getClass()) {
                return handler.collidesWith(instance1, instance2);
            }
        }
        // If we got here, we don't know how to handle this case.
        throw new CollisionNotHandledException();
    }
}
```

From here, you'd need to write a `CollisionHandler` for each case.  Perhaps you could write a `CollisionHandler` which merely checks that the two classes are the same, and in that case, asks the `BoundingBox` instance to perform the check on its own:

```
public class SelfCollisionHandler {
    public boolean canHandle(Class<? extends BoundingBox> class1, Class<? extends BoundingBox> class2) {
        return class1.equals(class2);
    }

    public boolean collidesWith(BoundingBox instance1, BoundingBox instance2) {
        return instance1.collidesWith(instance2);
    }
}
```

Then each implementation of `BoundingBox` would be responsible for implementing collision with its own instance.  For other cases, you would handle by having a specific `CollisionHandler` devoted to that particular case such as collision between `BoundingBoxRectangle` and `BoundingBoxCircle`.